# cant add paramater when caling view with search function in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

In cakephp I have a search function which uses parameters and call backs. My issue is that I want to call this function with a parameter but the function cant accept parameters when called.

```
//I cant call this function with a paramater 
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'email_list',$id,));
```

....

```
 public function email_list($search = 0) {

        $this->set( 'search',$search);

          ;

           if (($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put'))) {

              if (isset($this->request->data['searchFilter'])) {    
               $filter_url['controller'] = $this->request->params['controller'];
               $filter_url['action'] = $this->request->params['action'];
               $filter_url['page'] = 1;

        // for each filter we will add a GET parameter for the generated url
        foreach($this->data['User'] as $name => $value){
           if($value){
               $filter_url[$name] = urlencode($value);
           }
        }   
        //Post params are now GET paramaters
        return $this->redirect($filter_url);  



         }//isset
```

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're looking for. Is it like you're submitting a POST request and then converting the POST data to GET? It doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: I think its the other way if you are using redirect than how can it be post request and also there is an extra ',' in your redirect code

Comment: Use this plugin for a proper implementation of the PRG pattern https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search

Comment: The search function submits a post request and then turns it into a get request. This is standard practice approach for a search. This seems to rule out calling the function with a get . The problem is simple .

Comment: Also the code is proper implementation of a search in cakephp 2.X.

Comment: you can use CakeDC search plugin, its easy to use and fulfills your requirement. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495110/search-with-two-fields-not-mandatory/33496934#33496934)

Comment: My problems is not my search as it works fine. It is entering the search function with a paramater set

Comment: @ajt it works for parameter set

Comment: I worked out  a solution using a session variable that gets destroyed on entry. It is quick and easy. Having to redo a search function in cakephp ver 2 is not something i want to do. I am updating to cakephp ver 3

Answer (score 0):

worked out a solution using a session variable that gets destroyed on entry. It is quick and easy. Having to redo a search function in cakephp ver 2 is not something i want to do. I am updating to cakephp ver 3

```
 public function email_list($search = 0) {

    if ($this->Session->check('sessrowid'))
        {
           $searchRowId=$this->Session->read('sessrowid');   
           $this->Session->delete('sessrowid');


   }
```